# Not able to retrieve desired data from sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, analytic-functions

```
SELECT     
     a.alloc_date,
     p.plan,
     p.emp_id,
      a.veh,
     a.contri_type,
     a.amount,
     SUM (a.alloc_qty) AS sum_alloc_qty,                    -- 1000 funds distributed
     SUM (a.alloc_qty * a.amount) AS sum_alloc_value,       -- 1000*2 = 2000 
     COUNT (DISTINCT part_id) AS sum_emp_count,             -- 4 employees 
     MAX (a.alloc_qty * a.amount) AS max_value_to_one_emp,  --  600 
     null as "emp_count_with_max_value"                     --  Unable to retrieve -        idealy answer should be 3 in this example
 FROM   
     alloc a, emp p
 WHERE   
     A.alloc_date >= TO_DATE ('20111001', 'YYYYMMDD')
     AND a.emp_id = p.emp_id
GROUP BY   
     a.alloc_date,
     p.plan,
     p.emp_id,
     a.veh,
     a.contri_type,
     a.amount
ORDER BY   
     alloc_date, emp_id, amount
```

Here, the existing query is working like below.

Suppose, the company is distributing 1000 funds, wherein each fund's price is 2.

Now these 1000 funds are distributed amongst 4 employees.

Basic issue is to retrieve the maximum value of funds for one employee. Suppose, the distribution of fund is :

```
emp1=600 (300*2), emp2=600 (300*2), emp3=600 (300*2), emp4=300 (300*1)
```

So, here the maximum value of funds to one employee = 600.

This I am able to retrieve now by the query.

But, now the next issue is to retrieve another column (`emp_count_with_max_value`) which should be have the number of employees awarded this maximum value under each group.

In our example it turns out to be 3 employees. But I am unable to retrieve the same

Here I have given data for only one group. Resulting query output should be like below:

```
'11/12/86','abc','E25','pqr','qvr',2,1000,2000,4,600,3
```

Comment: How many rows per group do you have in your result? Do you have one row per employee?

Comment: @Scott: I am trying to use count(*) over (partition by MAX (a.alloc_qty * a.amount) ) as "emp_count_with_max_value".....but its giving me wrong output

Comment: @aF:The exisiting query is giving one record per group ....but internally it is grouping 4 employees (emp1,2,3...4 ) as given by example

Comment: @user1138658 then why don't you use the internally result and make a count() of the employees that have the `a.alloc_qty * a.amount equal to max_value_to_one_emp`?

Comment: @aF.:that is what i am unable to do :(

Comment: If you `group` by emp_id, the query needs to return more than 1 row, right?

Comment: @aF.Yes ....but we don't want to change the group by here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you rank the employees' allocations it is easy to determine who got the biggest amount.  Then you need to have an outer query to calculate the number of lucky dogs.

```
select alloc_date,
       plan,
       emp_id,
       veh,
       contri_type,
       amount,
       sum_alloc_qty,                    
       sum_alloc_value,      
       sum_emp_count,      
       max_value_to_one_emp,  
       sum ( case when rnk = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as emp_count_with_max_value
from (
    SELECT     a.alloc_date,
           p.plan,
           p.emp_id,
           a.veh,
           a.contri_type,
           a.amount,
           SUM (a.alloc_qty) AS sum_alloc_qty,                    -- 1000 funds distributed
           SUM (a.alloc_qty * a.amount) AS sum_alloc_value,       -- 1000*2 = 2000 
           COUNT (DISTINCT part_id) AS sum_emp_count,             -- 4 employees 
           MAX (a.alloc_qty * a.amount) AS max_value_to_one_emp,  --  600 
           dense_rank() over  (order by a.alloc_qty desc)      rnk  -- rank allocation in descending order
           FROM   alloc a, emp p
       WHERE   A.alloc_date >= TO_DATE ('20111001', 'YYYYMMDD')
           AND a.emp_id = p.emp_id
    GROUP BY   a.alloc_date,
           p.plan,
           p.emp_id,
           a.veh,
           a.contri_type,
           a.amount
)
group by alloc_date,
       plan,
       emp_id,
       veh,
       contri_type,
       amount,
       sum_alloc_qty,                    
       sum_alloc_value,      
       sum_emp_count,      
       max_value_to_one_emp
ORDER BY   alloc_date,
       emp_id,
       amount
```

Note: in the absence of test data I haven't tested this code, and I'm not guaranteeing it to be bug-free.  However the principle is sound.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to group by alloc_qty too but if you use this:

```
count(*) keep (dense_rank last order by A.ALLOC_QTY * A.AMOUNT) over () as "emp_count_with_max_value"
```

That should return the number of records matching the maximum. So, integrated into your code it should be something like:

```
SELECT     a.alloc_date,
       p.plan,
       p.emp_id,
       a.veh,
       a.contri_type,
       a.amount,
       SUM (a.alloc_qty) AS sum_alloc_qty,                    -- 1000 funds distributed
       SUM (a.alloc_qty * a.amount) AS sum_alloc_value,       -- 1000*2 = 2000 
       COUNT (DISTINCT part_id) AS sum_emp_count,             -- 4 employees 
       MAX (a.alloc_qty * a.amount) AS max_value_to_one_emp,  --  600 
       count(*) keep (dense_rank last order by A.ALLOC_QTY * A.AMOUNT) over () as "emp_count_with_max_value"                     --  Unable to retrieve -           idealy answer should be 3 in this example
    FROM   alloc a, emp p
   WHERE   A.alloc_date >= TO_DATE ('20111001', 'YYYYMMDD')
       AND a.emp_id = p.emp_id
GROUP BY   a.alloc_qty,
       a.alloc_date,
       p.plan,
       p.emp_id,
       a.veh,
       a.contri_type,
       a.amount
ORDER BY   alloc_date,
       emp_id,
       amount
```

You may also want to change your sum_emp_count to

```
COUNT (DISTINCT part_id) over ()
```

and max_value_to_one_emp to

```
MAX (a.alloc_qty * a.amount) over ()
```

As otherwise you will not get the value over all the data set.